# Floating Box in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm sorry if my topic doesn't suit my question. I'm new to Angular and I'm practicing by building an app. I want to achieve this kind of effect:

[image]

I have a button and when the button is clicked, I want to have a floating box like this. What is the best way to do this in Angular? If I would do it, I put the HTML of the box in my view and call a controller method every time the button is clicked to toggle the display of the block (using `ng-show`). Is that a good method? What method would you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a decent approach

Answer (score 2):

Use the angular ui bootstrap popover directive.

Here is a link: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

You will have to edit the template to inject custom html though.

Hope this helps.